# npm xlsx Any possible way to excel data to json inner onject

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to change my excel file to json in my angular 4 application.
using xlsx modules but it read only single objects. i want to read inner objects also.

i want to read this file in following json format. any one help me

```
{
 "quesitonEng":"ques....",
 options:{
      "opt1":"opt data...",
      "opt2":"opt data 2"
  }
}
```

but now it was read only in single object

[image: having this type of questions and options]